# C# generic list with many types

Tags: c#, generics

I might have worded the title incorrectly but basically what I am wanting to do is have a list of the same object, that has different generic types within it.

The example being this, I have a Tower Defence game that works using a Tile based map. So I have layers (tile layer, object layer, ai layer). So I have this class:

```
 public class Layer<T>{

    // The name of the layer
    private String name;

    // All the cells in this layer
    private Cell<T>[] cells; 

    public Layer(Map map, String name){
        cells = new Cell<T>[map.Width * map.Height];
        this.name = name;
        CreateCells();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fills the array of cells with blank, unoccupied cells
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateCells(){
        var index = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < cells.Length; x++){
            for (var y = 0; y < cells.Length; y++){
                cells[index] = new Cell<T>(x, y);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Gets the array of cells in this layer
    public Cell<T>[] GetCells(){
        return cells;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a cell at a specific index/coordinate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <returns>The cell at the X and Y coordinate/index</returns>
    public Cell<T> GetCellAt(int x, int y){
        foreach (var c in cells){
            if (c.GetX() != x || c.GetY() != y) continue;
            return c;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cell not found at " + x+"x"+y);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of this layer
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public String GetName(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

Now this is fine, this means I can specify a layer that holds a type of object. In the tile layer I want cells that can hold tiles, in objects I want the layer to hold objects etc etc.

Problem is, when I try to create a list of layers in my map class. I am not quite sure on the syntax for a so called "wildcard" type thing like in java (?).

I tried this, to no success:

```
      private List<Layer<dynamic>> layers;
```

It freaks out when I do this:

```
            layers = new List<Layer<dynamic>>();
        layers.Add(new Layer<Tile>(this, "tiles"));
```

So I am obviously using the incorrect syntax for this.

What should I do in this case?

UPDATE 1:

Following suggestions from people, I have tried using an interface for the common methods inside layer (get cell and what not). The problem with this design is that the layer requires type T in order to determine what type of object each cell can use.

UPDATE 2:

I can not figure out a way to do this any other way, so I decided to go with this solution:

Removed generics all together (almost) and instead of giving cell type T for occupant, I gave it type of GameObject. Now most things do inherit from game object (towers, tiles, obstacles, particles) however none of the AI related code does, so I need to unfortunately change my path finding code to do so.

I now have the following:

```
   public class Layer{

    // The name of the layer
    private String name;

    // All the cells in this layer
    private Cell[] cells; 

}
```

Generics have been removed from the Cell class as well:

```
    public class Cell{

    // The object inside this cell
    private GameObject occupant; // Note the new occupant type
    // The width and height of the cell in world coordinates
    public const float WIDTH = 1, HEIGHT = 1;
    // The coordinate of this cell
    private int x, y;
}
```

Now I am using a generic method inside the Cell class like so:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Gets the occupant in this cell
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T GetOccupant<T>() where T : GameObject{
        return occupant as T;
    }
```

So this code here, works as intended:

```
            layers = new List<Layer>();
        layers.Add(new Layer(this, "tiles"));
        GetLayer("tiles").GetCellAt(5, 5).SetOccupant(new EnemyScientist(null, 5, 1, 6));
        Enemy e = GetLayer("tiles").GetCellAt(5, 5).GetOccupant<Enemy>();
```

Although not the nicest looking code, the map system will only be used for this game so I am not particularly worried about writing re-usable code, mostly functional code. Ignore the fact that I have just stuck an enemy in the tile layer but I will add some sort of cheap check (typeof) to make sure I don't mess that up somewhere.

Comment: `new List<Layer<object>>` maybe? Also C# has generic constraints - look up `where` in the documetnation.

Comment: Have you considered implementing an interface with the common bits? The list could then be `List<IInterfaceType`. Note that `List<Layer<object>>` will not work, unless you constrain it to being an `out` generic type and only of type `class`. `out` also only works with interfaces and delegates, which means you can't really do this with only the types themselves.

Comment: I could remove generic type for Layer and instead have Layer inherit and interface yes, this might actually be a goo choice given that every single layer will have the same fields

Comment: I'd look into what @LasseV.Karlsen suggested. What do you intend to do with your list of layers? If you're iterating through them, or going to apply some common operation, it seems like there will be common behaviour, an ideal candidate for an interface. It's a good idea to look for this kind of definition up front in a statically typed language, or you tend to find you'll be dealing with a lot of casting further down the line.

Comment: @Chris my layers will be used to fetch whatever is in the cell on the given layer. So if you can imagine I want to place a tower, first we grab the Objects layer and make sure a tower does not already exist, if not we then check the tile layer to ensure the "terrain" can accept a tower, if so place it and then we check the AI layer to find out what entities where using that tile for navigation using the AI layer and adjust paths.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Layer<Tile>` and `Layer<Ai>` don't have any parent class in common that you could cast both to. The closest is the very general `object` that all reference types inherit from.

A common approach in this situation is, as Lasse suggests, define a common interface that they all inherit from:

```
interface ILayer 
{
    void CreateCells();
}

public class Layer<T> : ILayer 
{
```

Then your map can have a `List` of `ILayer`s:

```
layers = new List<ILayer>();
layers.Add(new Layer<Tile>(this, "Tiles"));
```

You'll need to think of a way to design your `ILayer` interface in such a way that it is not dependent on the generic parameter `T`.

Comment: Thank you, this is looking more and more like the most probable solution to the problem

Comment: Just read your edit and a problem with this, the layer needs a type T to determine what type each cell can hold. So an interface might not actually work here

Comment: @Gibbo The Layer class can still have a generic type `T` (see the line where I used `public class Layer<T> : Layer {`). It's simply that your map class needs to be agnostic to `T` w.r.t. how it stores and interacts with the layers. (For example, you might need to have `Cell<T>` inherit from `Cell` so that your `GetCells()` can return `List<Cell>` instead of `List<Cell<T>>`).

Comment: Apologies, I just re-read your post and I got mixed up due to both the class called Layer and the interface called LAyer

Comment: @Gibbo No worries. :) I've now renamed the interface to `ILayer` to be in line with .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Framework library it is implemented like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var layers = new List<ILayer<object>>();
        layers.Add(new Layer<string>()); // It is covariance so we can only use reference types.
    }
}

public interface ILayer<out T>
{
    void CreateCells();
    ICell<T>[] GetCells();
}

public class Layer<T> : ILayer<T>
{ }

public interface ICell<out T>
{ }

public class Cell<T> : ICell<T>
{ }
```

Comment: This will compile, but I'm not sure it will ultimately provide any benefit, and it opens up the possibility for runtime exceptions that wouldn't otherwise happen. Like this: `var layers = new List<ILayer<object>>; layers.Add(new Layer<Tile>()); ICell<object>[] arr = layers[0].GetCells(); arr[0] = new Cell<Ai>(); // runtine exception` `out` shouldn't be used as a way to just get the compiler to ignore type safety.

Comment: Yes the object's box can not be change to another type after it's been assigned. means this is ok: ICell<object> cell = new Cell<Ai>();